# Keep getting undefined index error, cant figure out how to declare value in the submodal window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP and MYSQL, I really need your help.  I am attempting to insert new information into the database, and installed the submodal feature to input and view customer notes.  I am attempting to Insert a "New Customer" into the database, and keep getting undefined index error for the "Notes" field...I am not sure how to declare the value since I am using the submodal feature and also have an Image that the user will click on to activate the submodal.  Here is the code for the table...thank you all very much!!

```
 <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form1" target="_top" id="form1">
<table width="30%%" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>First Name:</td>
  <td><label for="First_Name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last Name:</td>
  <td><label for="Last_Name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td><label for="Address"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>City:</td>
  <td><label for="City"></label>
  <input type="text" name="City" id="City" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Zip:</td>
  <td><label for="Zip"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Zip" id="Zip" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone:</td>
  <td><label for="Phone"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>E-Mail:</td>
  <td><label for="Email"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fee:</td>
  <td><label for="Fee"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Fee" id="Fee" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Referral Source:</td>
  <td><label for="Referral_Source"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Referral_Source" id="Referral_Source" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Notes:</td>
  <td><a href="subform.php?Id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" class="submodal"><img     
  src="Images/editnote.png" class="pencil" width="33" height="33" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
```

```
 Notice: Undefined index: Notes in /home/content/02/8116402/html/testleadform.php on line 55

                        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes'], "text"));


 Notice: Undefined index: Notes in /home/content/02/8116402/html/testleadform.php on line 55

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at    
/home/content/02/8116402/html/testleadform.php:55) in /home/content/02/8116402/html/testleadform.php       
on  line 65

Line 65: header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));




<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/cms.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) :    
 mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
 case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
}
```

}

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Leads (First_Name, Last_Name, Address, City, `State`, Zip, Phone,   
Email, Fee, Referral_Source, Notes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['First_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Last_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['City'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['State'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Zip'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Phone'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fee'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Referral_Source'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $cms) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "leads.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
 header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM Leads";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $cms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: What is this "submodal feature" you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

Did you access this page through a form? If not, `$_POST` does not exist. Also if there is not a field known as `Notes` (case sensitive - i.e. `<input name="Notes">`), then this field is non-existent and will throw this type of error. If it is returning to this page, check that `$_POST` exists with `if(isset($_POST))` before trying to access the variable.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you are getting an undefined index error in your Notes: section, then `$row_Recordset1['Id'];` does not exist. Make sure that your database field is `Id` (case sensitive) and not `ID`, `id`, or some variation. `class="submodal"` looks like HTML code and should not effect this issue.

Comment: I find it amusing that you said "or some variation" when there was only one more variation available

Comment: I just updated my question...I pasted the error and the line in question..I know that I am not declaring the value of Notes, I can't figure out how with the submodal feature and the image..

Answer (score 0):

If it is valid for `$row_Recordset1['Id']` to be unset, try doing the following:

```
<a href="subform.php?Id=<?php if (isset($row_Recordset1['Id'])) { echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; } ?>" class="submodal">
```

Comment: The error you received is not from the code you pasted above. Look at the error message. You'll see it's from `/home/content/02/8116402/html/testleadform.php on line 55`. I'm assuming $_POST['Notes'] does not exist.

Comment: @ Mike Exactly, that was my question...I am not sure how to set the value for it in the table... <td>Notes:</td>
  <td><a href="subform.php?Id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" class="submodal"><img     
  src="Images/editnote.png" class="pencil" width="33" height="33" /></a></td>...

Comment: I also hope that you change that custom error handler you are using when you put this in a production environment since it seems to print out the line of the file that had the error. This is great for testing, but can be a huge security problem if (for example) line 10 contains a missing `;` and line 11 contains some super secret code (like DB username and password). This super secret code will then be echoed to the browser.

Comment: Your problem does not lie anywhere in the code above. It has nothing to do with what you just pasted. That part is working fine (at least it's not what's producing your above error). Make sure you are looking at the line that contains `GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes'], "text"));`

Comment: Ok, I got it.  Still can't find the issue anywhere...I'll paste the code that I am using above, maybe you can catch it...I spent 3 hours on this, can't seem to figure it out....